# Automatically choose a file location before loading it in php

Tags: php

I need to create a simple file overloading system like symfony does with php files and templates. I will give an example to explain what I need:

Given this folder structure:

```
 - root_folder
    - modules
       -module1
         -file1.php
         -file2.php
         -file3.php

    - specific_modules
       -module1
         -file2.php
```

I would like to find a way that automatically loads a file if it is found inside the specific_modules folder (file2.php) when called, if it is not found, it should load file2.php normally from the modules directory.

I would like to do it unobstrusively for the programmer, but not sure if it's possible!!

Any help or advice is welcome, thanks in advance!

skarvin

Answer (score 2):

If the files contain only objects with the same name, then you can write your own autoloader function and register it with [`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Perhaps something like

```
function my_loader($class)
{
    // look in specific_modules dir for $class
    // if not there, look in modules dir for $class
}
spl_autoload_register('my_loader');
```

This will allow you to code simply as:

```
$obj = new Thing();
```

And if Thing is defined in specific_modules, it will use that one, else the default one.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. My problem is that I'm dealing with a very old site without any classes at all. The file structure is as it's shown on my post. I would like to copy the same behaviour with classes but including only the specific files in specific_modules when they are found. I know that I could include a function on each file doing this check but I would like to know whether or not exists an unobstrusive way to do it.

Thanks a lot anyways!

Answer (score 1):

```
$normal_dir = 'modules';
$specific_dir = 'specific_modules';

$modules = array('module1' => array('file1.php','file2.php','file3.php'));

foreach($modules as $module => $files)
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        if(!file_exists("$specific_dir/$module/$file"))
        {
            include("$normal_dir/$module/$file");
        }
        else
        {
            include("$specific_dir/$module/$file");
        }
    }
}
```

This code will work as simply for you as possible, it makes it easy to add new files to your modules and change the directory names. By "load" I am making the assumption you mean include, but that part is easy enough to change.

Comment: I guess that implies using it on each file I want to check isn't it? Yes I meant include :)

Comment: @skarvin: Certainly, but the important part is the `file_exists` section. It'd be easy to re-work it into a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Alex's answer, you could also define an `__autoload` function:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/specific_modules/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require __DIR__ . '/specific_modules/' . $class_name . '.php';
    }
    elseif (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/modules/' . $class_name . '.php')) {
        require __DIR__ . '/modules/' . $class_name . '.php';
    }
    else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Then if you do `$obj = new Thing();` it will try to load `Thing.php` from those two directories.

Comment: Nice one, but as I answered to Alex, I am not using classes, just plain and old php files :/

Comment: So remove the first and last lines and you're set to go.